# Counting users based on an event count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an events table where I currently have a count of users grouped by the date. I am wanting to make two different counts based on the number of times a user had a specific event (we'll call it event_a) The first count will count the user if event_a appeared exactly 1 time for the user, the 2nd count will count the user if the event_a appeared more than once for the user.

I believe to achieve this I need a CASE WHEN, but I am unsure how to correctly write the code to give me the output I need. Currently this is what I have:

```
SELECT calendar_date,
  COUNT(distinct(users)) AS n_users,
  COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN eventName = 'event_a' THEN users END) AS n_users_event_a,
  COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN 'event_a' = 1 THEN userID END) AS bucket_a
  COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN 'event_a' > 1 THEN userID END) AS bucket_b
FROM e_table
WHERE calendar_date >= '2019-10-01'
  AND event_name IN ('event_a', 'event_b', 'event_c')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

When I run this code I get the error message:

> Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  Invalid input syntax for integer: "event_a"

Looking at my code and the error, it makes sense why I am seeing this error because I am trying to use a mathematical operation on a string. I believe I need to have some type of count within my count syntax, but I am unsure how to approach that. Am I on the right track, or is there a different way to approach this??

Comment: You are missing a closing single quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two levels of aggregation, one at the date/user level and the other just for the date:

```
SELECT calendar_date,
       COUNT(*) AS n_users,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE cnt_a > 0) AS n_users_event_a,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE cnt_a = 1) AS n_users_event_a_1,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE cnt_a > 1) AS n_users_event_a_2pl
FROM (SELECT calendar_date, user, eventName, count(*) as cnt,
             COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE eventName = 'event_a') as cnt_a
      FROM e_table
      WHERE calendar_date >= '2019-10-01' AND
            event_name IN ('event_a', 'event_b', 'event_c')
      GROUP BY calendar_date, user
     ) e
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

EDIT:

You can replace the `FILTER` with:

```
SELECT calendar_date,
       COUNT(*) AS n_users,
       SUM( (cnt_a > 0)::int ) AS n_users_event_a,
       SUM( (cnt_a = 1)::int ) AS n_users_event_a_1,
       SUM( (cnt_a > 1)::int ) AS n_users_event_a_2pl
```

Comment: I am getting an error when I try to run this:

>Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  Syntax error at or near "("

Looking at the query, I am unsure where the syntax error is occurring.

Comment: @EJWPF . . . What row is that error on?  The problem could be the `FILTER` clause if you are using an old version of Postgres.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. Did some testing and it seems to error out when I include the FILTER clause.

Comment: The replacement for filter worked for me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @EJWPF . . . Is there a reason you didn't accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT x.calendar_date
    , x.n_users
    , COUNT(DISTINCT y.users) AS n_users_event_a
    , SUM(CASE WHEN y.cnt = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bucket_a
    , SUM(CASE WHEN y.cnt > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bucket_b
FROM (
    SELECT calendar_date
        , COUNT(1) AS n_users
    FROM e_table
    WHERE calendar_date >= '2019-10-01' AND event_name IN (
            'event_a'
            , 'event_b'
            , 'event_c'
            )
    GROUP BY calendar_date
    ) x
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT users
        , calendar_date
        , count(1) AS cnt
    FROM e_table
    WHERE calendar_date >= '2019-10-01' AND event_name = 'event_a'
    GROUP BY users
        , calendar_date
    ) y ON x.calendar_date = y.calendar_date
GROUP BY x.calendar_date
    , x.n_users
```